# UITableViewCell is nil after insertRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a tableView, which initially has 4 sections with 1 row in each. Depending on the user interaction with the first row, I need to insert or delete a second row in the section. After that, I need to do the setup of the cell, which is next after tapped. Here's my code for handling interaction:

```
-(void) tableViewSwitchToggled: (UISwitch*) sender{
    targetSection = sender.tag; //each switch is added to cell's contentview and it's tag is set to indexPath.section
    UITableView* tableView = ...

    if (someBool){
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObject: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: 1 inSection: targetSection]] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        UITableViewCell* detailsCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: 0 inSection: targetSection + 1]]; //I try to get the first row of the next section and it is always nil!!!
        //do something with detailsCell content
    }
    else{
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObject: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: 1 inSection: targetSection]] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        UITableViewCell* detailsCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: 0 inSection: targetSection + 1]]; //and it works perfectly, giving me the cell address
         //do something with detailsCell content
    }
}
```

So here's my question - why do I get a nil cell after I insert a row? Isn't the tableView supposed to have all cells already allocated? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can only get a reference to a cell which is visible. You can ask the tableView for an array of cells that are visible (or their index paths, forget which). A cell is a temporal thing that exists while its visible - that's why you can recycle them.

What you need to do is note in code that when that cell re-appears, you want to do something special with it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Eventually I was able to solve my problem by putting one of the code parts in `tableView: willDisplayCell:  forRowAtIndexPath:` method

Comment: Exactly what I was saying. The cell didn't exist at the time you wanted to change it, but deferring until it was going to appear solved the problem.